# How to display current music position using FMOD and C++?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, fmod

I want to display the time that has elapsed as music plays in real-time.
FMOD's Core API provides `Channel::getPosition()` function to obtain the current position in milliseconds. I want to update the position every second.

I am a beginner and have no knowledge of multithreaded programming.

I call `Channel::getPosition()` in a loop and use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` to delay the loop for one second before the next iteration.

Here is the code:

```cpp
unsigned int position = 0;
std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(1000);
while(true) {
    channel -> getPosition(&position, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_MS);
    std::cout << postion / 1000 << "\n"; //Display seconds
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
}
```

However, I get some buggy output :

```
0
1
...
13
13
14
16
...
```

13 appears twice and 15 does not even appear. In another case, 5 appears twice.

I am thinking of rounding up or rounding down the number I obtain from `Channel::getPosition()` to correct the output.

How can I fix this?

**Note:** Error checking is omitted for simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `<chrono>` even for trivial timing functions.
2. Use the C++17 `round` function for truncating milliseconds to seconds for this example.  If you don't have C++17, steal `round` from [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html).
3. Use `sleep_until` instead of `sleep_for` in order to keep a more accurate "timespan" for each iteration of the loop.

Putting that all together:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

enum unit{FMOD_TIMEUNIT_MS};

struct Channel
{
    void getPosition(unsigned int* position, unit)
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        static auto start = steady_clock::now();
        *position = duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now()-start).count();
    } 
};

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto channel = std::make_unique<Channel>();
    auto constexpr timespan = 1s;
    auto next_start = system_clock::now() + timespan;
    while (true)
    {
        unsigned int position_as_integral;
        channel->getPosition(&position_as_integral, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_MS);
        milliseconds position{position_as_integral};
        std::cout << round<seconds>(position).count() << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_start);
        next_start += timespan;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is that `position / 1000` rounds down to the nearest integer and `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is not guaranteed to sleep for exactly the time you specify, and so you might get a duplicate or you might miss one.

Try this instead:

```
unsigned int position = 0;
std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(100);
unsigned last_sec = 0x7fffffff;

while(true) {
    channel -> getPosition(&position, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_MS);
    unsigned sec = position / 1000;
    if (sec != last_sec)
    {
        std::cout << sec << "\n"; //Display seconds
        last_sec = sec;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
}
```

Comment: Additionally, playback probably happens in another thread at another "rate" - so there's no precise "wall clock" time synchronization.

Comment: At line 3, shouldn't the argument be `1000` instead of `100`? Also, whenever we round down, that reading is omitted. Instead, can we print `sec + 1` if `sec == last_sec` or something like that?

Comment: No,  using 100 is deliberate.  Think about it. And if you want to round `sec` to thd nearest second, do `sec = (position + 500) / 1000;`